# Server Monitoring

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to code a program that reads the status of a list of servers, records the time they fail, stores it , and using this data it chooses a server that will MOST probably fail next time, and shows it. I will need some help to approach this problem. Will you suggest a Markov Chain Model? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am not a statistician*

Based on your available observation criteria, I would calculate the probability of a server down event as:

```
P(X = serverDown) = # of failures / # of observations
```

If you polled 100 times and the server was down 1 time, then probability the server will be down for your next poll is: 0.01.

Calculate P(X = severDown) for each of your servers, the server with the highest value for P(X = serverDown) is the one most likely to fail on your next poll.

You're only recording failure events, you need to know the time you started polling each server and the polling interval to calculate the # of observations.